# How to get the path and name of the current running jar?

Tags: java, jar

There are plenty of folders that let you find the folder that the running jar is in, but how do I get the running jar? For example, if foo.jar is in C:/FOO/foo.jar, then how would I get the path C:/FOO/foo.jar, not C:/FOO. Also, I have no idea A: if the jar was moved to a different folder, B: If my jar was renamed, and C: if there are other jars in the same folder as mine. I want to get a File object of the currently running jar, which I am then going to be using (in some way) to replace that jar with a new version of my program. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!
EDIT:
Wait a minute, would it be possible to, after finding the directory, scan through it looking for jar files, and in each jar file, check for a certain class/other file that is in my jar?

Comment: No, every other stackoverflow question I found wanted to get the directory the jar was in, I want the jar itself.

Comment: There is a misconception here. A running java-program consists of java-classes. These classes can originate from different sources from the classpath, including multiple JAR-files. Not one, multiple. There is no single jar-file to find, all you can do is looking into the classpath and scans that for jars.

Comment: How do I get the classpath? You are saying that in the classpath would have the paths to any and all jars that are loaded?

Comment: System.getProperty("java.class.path");

Answer (score 5):

Alright, I got it figured out. It's something like this:

```
File dir = new File(YourMainClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
String jar = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
File jarFile = new File(dir, jar);
```

Thanks everyone!
EDIT: Also, if I ever end up with multiple jars in the classpath, I would need something to check that I got the right one.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the path of jar, use:

```
File dir = new File(YourMainClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
```

To get the main class name, use:

```
StackTraceElement[] stack = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
StackTraceElement main = stack[stack.length - 1];
String mainClass = main.getClassName();
```

Then, use them all together:

```
File f = new File(dir, mainClass);
```

Comment: Just edited. Now you have the  *path of jar* and the *main class name* together.

Answer (score -1):

You can use find file JAVA API.

What you want is File.listFiles(FileNameFilter filter).

That will give you a list of the files in the directory you want that match a certain filter.

The code will look similar to